# testing true or false if it has numbers 1-9 in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to test if an array has numbers 1 through 9. I have 9 different arrays to test, so I'm trying to loop set of array one by one and convert it to a string and test that array if it has numbers 1 through 9. When I output my code, it comes out as

```
[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false]
```

The last one should come out false, because the array[8] does not contain all the numbers from 1 to 9. I'm not sure if my regex coding is wrong, but the test prints out true for arrays that should be false.

```
function doneOrNot(board){


  var numberTest = /[1-9]/g;
  var boardStr = "";
  var boardTest;
  var testResult = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      boardStr = board[i].toString();
      boardTest = numberTest.test(boardStr);
      testResult.push(boardTest);   
      console.log(boardStr);
    }

console.log(testResult);

}

doneOrNot([[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
       [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 9],
       [1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0],
       [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0],
       [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
       [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
       [9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4],
       [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
       [3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9]]);
```

Comment: When you say numbers 1 through 9, do you mean the array needs to contain all the numbers 1 through 9 (so every digit is present) or do you mean that the array must contain only numbers 1 through 9 and not anything else?  If it's the first option, then a regex does not do that in any way.  You will need a different kind of test entirely.

Comment: @jfriend00 contain all numbers from 1 through 9, so every digit is present.

Comment: OK, then a single regex has no ability to do what you are trying to do.  You will need an entirely different approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regex is simply not the right tool to use.  It does not tell you if every digit exists.  It tells you if any digit exists or a different form of the regex could tell you if nothing but digits exist, but it doesn't tell you if each digit exists (in any order).

---

Here's a conceptually simple approach for testing any given array to see if all digits 1-9 are present:

```
function test(arr) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (arr.indexOf(i) === -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And, you could combine that with your test data:

```
function doneOrNot(list) {
    return list.map(function(arr) {
        return test(arr);
    });
}

doneOrNot([[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
   [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 9],
   [1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0],
   [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0],
   [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
   [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
   [9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4],
   [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
   [3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9]]);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/w04b6frv/

---

FYI, there are probably fancier schemes that might perform better.  The point above was to find the conceptually simplest mechanism that would work and would tolerate any input as long as the array contained each of the 9 digits.

I don't understand all the constraints of the your test arrays, but if what you're really trying to see if if the arrays have exactly 9 elements in them that include all the digits from 1 to 9 and they can be in any order, then you could do that like this:

```
function test(arr) {
    var s = arr.slice(0).sort().toString();
    return s === "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6cdg5b3g/

---

And, here's a different approach that starts with  a 9-bit bitmask and then clears a bit each time it finds one of the 1-9 digits and then it can just see if the whole bitmask has been cleared at the end.  This version tolerates values outside the range of 1-9 (and an array longer than 9), but that could easily be changed by just checking to see if the length was `9` at the beginning.

```
function test(arr) {
    // initalize bits to 111111111 in binary
    // one bit for each value 1-9
    var bits = 511;
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
        // if the number is in range, then clear the appropriate bit
        if (item >= 1 && item <= 9) {
            bits &= ~(1 << (item - 1));
        }
    });
    // return if all bits have been cleared
    return bits === 0;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nt1mya4d/

Comment: Added two more versions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

```js
var testResult = board.map(function(arr) {
  arr = arr.slice().sort(); // Copy and sort
  for(var j=0; j<9; ++j)    // Iterate numbers
    if(arr[j] !== j+1) return false;
  return true;
});
```

```js
function doneOrNot(board){
  var testResult = board.map(function(arr) {
    arr = arr.slice().sort(); // Copy and sort
    for(var j=0; j<9; ++j)    // Iterate numbers
      if(arr[j] !== j+1) return false;
    return true;
  });
  console.log(testResult);
}
doneOrNot([[5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2], 
           [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 3, 4, 9],
           [1, 0, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0],
           [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0],
           [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
           [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
           [9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4],
           [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
           [3, 0, 0, 4, 8, 1, 1, 7, 9]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is that you are converting the whole row to a string and testing the whole row against the regular expression. So for this row:

`[9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4]`

We would expect `false` however:

`(/[1-9]/g).test([9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4].toString())` returns `true` because the string does indeed contain at least one of the expected numbers.

You could fix your could by using `match` instead of `test`. `match` will return the number of matches in the string so in this case:

`[9, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 1, 4].toString().match(/[1-9]/g)` returns `["9", "1", "5", "3", "7", "2", "1", "4"]`

Then you could count the match result length however what if the string contained two "9"? You need to make it unique too. I suggest simplifying the `doneOrNot` function to this:

```
var done = '123456789';

function doneOrNot(board) {
    var results = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        var boardStr = board[i].sort().join('');
        results.push(boardStr === done);
    }
    console.log(results);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99bxLt3s/

A better solution would be to use another library that gave you Array equality checking. Then you could write your code like this:

```
var done = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function doneOrNot(board) {
    var results = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        results.push(ArrayEquals(board[i], done));
    }
    console.log(results);
}
```

Where `ArrayEquals` is the function that compares two arrays for equality from an outside library.